# Nearest-neighbour "pixelly" texture scaling in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to scale a sprite, but have the texture be scaled in a "pixelly" way, like retro games.

I know how to do this in OpenGL, but I'm not sure how to do this in Cocos2d.

How do I do this? Is there a way of getting at the OpenGL? Or something through Cocos2d?

Answer (score 7):

With Cocos2d 0.8 (latest) it is very easy...

You just call setAliasTexParameters on your texture...

for example:

Sprite *aSprite = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"someTextureImage.png"];

[aSprite.texture setAliasTexParameters];

Answer (score 2):

For Cocos2dx v3, you can do this in a very similar way

```
Sprite* my_sprite = Sprite::create("my_image.png");
my_sprite->getTexture()->setAliasTexParameters();
my_sprite->setScale(4);
```

And that'll scale it something like nearest neighbor.

Comment: Didn't see a question for this about xv3, so I thought I'd add it in anyway.